# confusion about ASCII linefeed byte in awk + xxd bash command

Tags: bash, binary, hex, end-of-line, xxd

I am confused about some `0a` (i.e. `NL` ASCII byte) happening in some bash commands. On the following:

```
$ echo | sha1sum $1 | awk '{print $1;}' | xxd -r -ps > test.bin
$ echo | sha1sum $1 | awk '{print $1;}' > test.hex
$ xxd test.bin
00000000: adc8 3b19 e793 491b 1c6e a0fd 8b46 cd9f  ..;...I..n...F..
00000010: 32e5 92fc                                2...
$ xxd test.hex
00000000: 6164 6338 3362 3139 6537 3933 3439 3162  adc83b19e793491b
00000010: 3163 3665 6130 6664 3862 3436 6364 3966  1c6ea0fd8b46cd9f
00000020: 3332 6535 3932 6663 0a                   32e592fc.
```

what is responsible for the `0a` byte to be present in `test.hex` but not in `test.bin`?

**Note 1**: this is a question that I have been asking myself following the solution used there:

[Dump a ```sha``` checksum output to disk in binary format instead of plaintext hex in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60490752/dump-a-sha-checksum-output-to-disk-in-binary-format-instead-of-plaintext-h)

**Note 2**: I am able to suppress the `0a` byte, this is not the question, I am just curious of why it is present in one case but not the other:

```
$ echo | sha1sum $1 | awk '{print $1;}' | head -c-1 > test_2.hex
$ xxd test_2.hex
00000000: 6164 6338 3362 3139 6537 3933 3439 3162  adc83b19e793491b
00000010: 3163 3665 6130 6664 3862 3436 6364 3966  1c6ea0fd8b46cd9f
00000020: 3332 6535 3932 6663                      32e592fc
```

Comment: That awk command WILL generate a linefeed at the end of each line of output so your real question is just about xxd, Specifically "why does `xxd -r -ps` remove the linefeed". Have you looked up the man page to see what it says?

Comment: Ok, thank you, I was confused there. So indeed ```xxd``` removes this thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `0a` that you are seeing is coming from `awk`.  By default the *output record separator* for `awk` is `\n` and you can remote it by setting the `ORS` (e.g. with a `BEGIN {ORS=""}`).

You lose it when you pipe through `xxd -r -ps` due to the `-r` parameter. From the man page: "Additional Whitespace and line-breaks are allowed anywhere."